# Running DevDemon Tagger inside an embed

Tags: parse-order, devdemon-tagger

Here's my code:

```
{exp:channel:entries entry_id="{embed:id}"}     
    {exp:tagger:tags entry_id="{entry_id}" backspace="2"}{tagger:tag_name}, {/exp:tagger:tags}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

It spits out entry_id just fine. Is there a way to delay Tagger? Seems like it's not getting the entry_id passed. If I hard code an id in, I get the resutling tags, but this approach yields nothing. Thanks!

I also tried running this with just {embed:id} in the place of {entry_id} with the same results.

The whole embed:

```
<div class="tile-content {embed:posttype}">
    <div class="content-pad">

        <i class="fa {embed:icon}"></i>

        <h3>{embed:title}</h3>

        <div class="hashtags">
            <p>{exp:tagger:tags entry_id="{embed:id}" backspace="2"}{tagger:tag_name}, {/exp:tagger:tags}</p>
        </div>

        <div class="blocked">

            <p>{embed:teaser}</p>

            {if embed:type == 'article'}
                <a class="btn btn-white" href="{embed:link}" target="_blank">READ MORE</a>
            {/if}

            {if embed:type == 'blog-post' OR embed:type == 'exec'}
                <a class="btn btn-white" href="{embed:link}">Read More</a>
            {/if}

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's pulling in the data from here:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="post" orderby="random" limit="1020" paginate="bottom"}
    {exp:switchee variable = "{the_post_type}" parse="inward"}
        {case value="article"}

            {embed="tile/index"
                icon="fa-newspaper-o"
                title="{title}"
                teaser="{post_teaser}"
                link="{post_source}"
                type="{the_post_type}"
                id="{entry_id}"
                posttype="{post_type}"
            }

        {/case}
    {/exp:switchee}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Where/how are you setting `entry_id="{embed:id}"`? I'd like to see your other template too.

Comment: Updated my code to answer your question... I'm running them as embeds to keep my views separated out but I might have to bring them all inline.

Comment: I'd say it's parsing issue, as is the case in most EE instances, have you tried `parse="inward"` on your channel entries loop?

Comment: Also what happens when you remove the `switchee` tag?